Masstransit with version 8 in producers and version 7 in consumer
We have our application that is using Masstransit version 7.2.4 with RabbitMq. Both producers and consumers are using Masstransit version 7.2.4 and we are using direct queue binding.
Everything works fine, except recently a new service coming from a different team that is publishing on our RabbitMq. They are using Masstransit version 8.0.x, and they are publishing the message type without any physical binding.
They have other team that is consuming their messages using Masstransit 8 without any physical binding and only adding the consumer type, and add the code
cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);

The other consumer working fine.
But on our side I didn't find a way to bind from our 7.2.4 consumer.
So in order to find out if the different version is changing the behavior, I created a simple producer that is using version 8.0.0, and two consumers one with version 8.0.0, and one with 7.2.4.
Version 8.0 consumer worked out of the shelf.
Version 7.2.4 consumer didn't work.
Here are the details:
The producer is created form mtworker template and it has a background worker service that is publishing HelloMessage
// program.cs of producer
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                    {
                        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

                        x.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h => { 
                                h.Username("guest");
                                h.Password("guest");
                            });
                            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
                        } );
                    });
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

And the background worker as follows:
    public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly IBus _bus;

        public Worker(IBus bus)
        {
            _bus = bus;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                await _bus.Publish(new HelloMessage
                {
                    Name = "Some message"
                }, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }


Hello Message is defined in a shared class library with namespace MessageShared
// message.cs
namespace MessageShared;
public class HelloMessage
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

When I run the producer, it will create this Exchange in RabbitMq

===================================================================
Now on the consumer V8 side:
It is as well mtworker
// program.cs on consumer v8

services.AddMassTransit(x =>
                    {
                        x.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

                        var entryAssembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();

                        x.AddConsumers(entryAssembly);
                        x.UsingRabbitMq((ctx, cfg) =>
                        {
                            cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
                            {
                                h.Username("guest");
                                h.Password("guest");
                            });
                            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(ctx);
                        } );
                    });


The consumer is as follows:
// HelloMessageConsumer
public class HelloMessageConsumer : IConsumer<HelloMessage>
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HelloMessageConsumer> _logger;

        public HelloMessageConsumer(ILogger<HelloMessageConsumer> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<HelloMessage> context)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello {Name}", context.Message.Name);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

public class HelloConsumerDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<HelloMessageConsumer>
    {
        protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<HelloMessageConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
        {
            endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Intervals(500, 1000));
        }        
    }


When I run the v8 consumer it works out of the shelf, and it consumer the messages, and it automatically create these extra exchange and queue

And the queue

======================================================================
Now for the consumer v7.2.4
Everything is almost the same as the consumer version 8, but it use MassTransit v7.2.4.
But nothing work with 7.2.4
and those extra exchange and queue that automatically get created on v8 are not being created.
Is there a way to consumer that message without upgrading our masstransit, and without forcing the other team to do a physical binding to a physical queue?

Commercial support includes Technical Guidance on version upgrades and ensuring compatibility without requiring all services to be upgraded. V8 is backwards compatible with V7 at the message and broker topology level.
